# Android SDK - convert bitmap to resource for layout params issue

Tags: android

For some reason, when I create a bitmap from an image in asset, it does not display fullscreen.  When I take an image from drawable, resId, the image shows fullscreen.  Why is this?

```
            //the image is not fullscreen
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmapFileFromAssetorSD);

            //this makes the image fullscreen
        //iv.setBackgroundResource(resId);

        iv.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the appropriate [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

```
ImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
```